# имитация действий человека nodejs

Tags: node.js, node-modules

может есть какие-нибудь модули к nodejs с помощью которых можно к примеру нажать на кнопку на каком-нибудь сайте, например чтоб авторизоваться где нибудь(osmosis как я понял не выпущен для десятой версии)

Comment: А чем selenium не понравился? https://www.npmjs.com/package/selenium-webdriver

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете попробовать http://phantomjs.org/, он позволяет открывать страницы и выполнять определенные действия на ней, по сути это браузер которым вы можете управлять программно